# openssl command to verify the cipher of the ssl cert

Tags: tls, certificate, openssl

Is it possible to use an openssl command in order to check the cipher of an SSL Certificate on a live website?

For example to use something like:
`openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -crlf`

The above command will return a lot of information along with the cipher:
`Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`

I am looking for the openssl command that will return only the cipher value.

Comment: That looks that  you need to script the output of that command, that is not a security question.

Comment: `openssl s_client` does not have the option to only do this but the output could be post-processed or it could be done instead with some Python or Perl or whatever code, like `perl -MIO::Socket::SSL -E 'say IO::Socket::SSL->new("example.com:443")->get_cipher'`. But details on this not a security question.  Apart from that: this is not the *"cipher of the ssl cert"* but the cipher from the TLS handshake. A **certificate itself has no cipher** and only slightly influences what ciphers can be used in the TLS handshake. This means **different ciphers can be used with the same certificate**.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich so how to check if an ssl/tls cert is vulnerable to common known attacks? Except the SSL/TLS version, the cipher is not a good info for auditing perposes?

Comment: I have no idea what *"... common known attacks ..."* you refer to. There are attacks at the TLS level which are independent of the certificate, some are associated with specific ciphers while others not. There are TLS specific attacks against the application layer, which neither depend on the certificate nor on the cipher used. There are weak signatures used in the certificate which do not depend on TLS but are a property of the certificate. Apart from this - this is a different question than the original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Try grepping

```
$ echo -n '' | openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 2>&1 | grep -Po "(?<=Cipher is ).*$"
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

Or you can also wrap it into a function like so...

```
$ function get-s_clientCipher {
    echo -n '' | 
    openssl s_client -connect $1 2>&1 | 
    grep --perl-regexp --only-matching -- "(?<=Cipher is ).*$";
}
```

...and then use it like so...

```
$ get-s_clientCipher example.com:443
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

But I'm not sure exactly if that is going to be very helpful to you. Because the result depends very much on your local environment. So it will have very little general meaning. -- So if you want to get a more general diagnosis of a server's ciphers, then use something like the https://testssl.sh/ shell script. (Or if the server is reachable from the internet try https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ )